# Removing duplicates from list: Keeping the order and the last duplicate of each element

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a ordered list with duplicates (objects that compare equal) and I want to remove the duplicates. As I want to keep the order, I cannot use `set`.

The duplicates in my list don't ocurr directly after each other and I want to keep the last ocurrence. In [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order), it seems like only the first ocurrence of a duplicate is kept.

As I simplified example, this is what I want:

```
list_with_duplicates = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
list_without_duplicates = [3, 2, 1]
```

The only thing I can think of is a messy implementation using multiple iterations to first save the last ocurrence of each duplicate and then recreating the original list using the order of the last ocurring duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any answer you like in the linked duplicate (such as the [top one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480227/2617068)), with one change: reverse your list before you iterate over it, and reverse the result when you're done.

```
def rem_rev(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq[::-1] if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))][::-1]
    #                     ^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^
    #                  or reversed(seq)
```

Comment: I don't really get the boolean expression to be honest. What is the `or seen_add(x)` for? I guess it somehow adds `x` to `seen` if it's not already there but I don't know how or what the return value for that would be.

Comment: @CGFoX - For each element in `seq[::-1]`, it only includes that element in the resulting list if it isn't in `seen`. If `x in seen` isn't the case, it checks the result of adding `x` to `seen`, which returns `None`. It's basically "include it if it's not there, or add it if it's not."

Answer (score 2):

For Python >= 3.7, `dict` is ordered, so a simple solution is:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
>>> list(reversed(dict.fromkeys(reversed(x))))
[3, 2, 1]
```

or:

```
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(x[::-1]))[::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
```

For earlier Python versions, use `OrderedDict` instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a clean solution too:

```
x = [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
sorted(set(x), key=lambda i: x[::-1].index(i), reverse=True)
# [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse a list using '::-1':

```
>>> result = []
>>> for item in l[::-1]:
...     if item not in result:
...             result.append(item)
... 
>>> result[::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def keep_second(x, y):
>>>     return y
>>> [functools.reduce(keep_second, group) for _, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(items, key=key_func), key=key_func)
```